# Determine the color space of a Mat Opencv

Tags: java, opencv, mat

I am working on a program where I have these contours I am looking at and I want to find the RGB values of each specific contour. The current problem I am facing is that I the mat is of CvType `CV32_F` . I change the images `rtype` to `CV_8UC3`. I want to know what color space the Mat is in so that I can convert it to the RGB spectrum. I never set the Mat to a color space so I am not sure which one it is. So I get conversion errors. I have tried BGR, GRAY and RGB2BGR( just to see if it was already in that spectrum and would change).  Here is my code:

```
private static void findRGBs(List<MatOfPoint> squareContours){
    for(int i = 0; i < squareContours.size(); i++){
        squareContours.get(i).convertTo(squareContours.get(i), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(squareContours.get(i), squareContours.get(i), Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);
         //not sure what color space this image is 
        getPixelValues(squareContours.get(i));
        foundFrames.add(squareContours.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look at mat.channels, it is probably 4 and you'll need BGRA2BGR or RGBA2BGR. Afaik there is no way ro deternine the color space other than "tracking" the color space manually. On PC and C++, the image is by default loaded as 8UC3 BGR. I guess on Android it is 8UC4 RGBA or BGRA by default.

Comment: It's a 2 channel image is there a way I can make it 3? And determine what it is? @Micka

Comment: did you capture it yourself? Where does that image/mat come from?

Comment: from the code it looks like those mats aren't images at all but sets of 2D points (contours). So they don't have any color space and you can't use them for algorithms that expect images as input. Maybe you have to draw those contours on images, but that depends on your task...

Comment: The image is RGB and I get the contours of that image. I never say what color space the List<MatOfPoint> I use to get the contours. It should be 3 channel if it was reading from the RGB but it's not. @Micka

Comment: But I thought they are Mats because MatOfPoint extends the Mat class. So it has those properties I think @Micka

Comment: Every image is a mat but not every mat is an image ;)

Comment: Then is it possible for me to determine the color of the contours in my image? I find the contours in my image and I would like to determine their RGB values. That's what I am trying to do at a high level @Micka

Comment: you can create a mask by drawing the contour filled in white on a black 8UC1 image. Then test for each pixel of your input image (which probably is BGR or BGRA) whether its mask pixel is white and evaluate the color in the input image then. You can optimize this by masking and evaluating bounding box area of the contours only.

Comment: When drawing the contour on a black image that. So I would then iterate over the pixels of that black image? Giving me the RGB values of the contours? @Micka

Comment: you iterate over image coordinates (your input image and the mask have same resolution). Then test: If mask(pixelPosition)==255  : evaluate inputImage(pixelPosition)

Comment: @Micka alright I think I get it :) so I draw the found contours as white on a black image and I iterate through both images if I meet white in the black image I go to the same coordinates on the main image and get their values. I believe that is what you are saying

Comment: yes, that sounds right.

Comment: thanks for the help :) I will let you know how it goes. I am currently implementing it. @Micka